# tuple of const references: cannot convert from int to const <T> &

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile the following code using VS2010:

```
typedef enum EPinDirection{
    EPinDirection_Unknown,
    EPinDirection_In,
    EPinDirection_Out
};

class cPin{
    std::tuple<QString,EPinDirection> m_nameDir;

public:
    cPin(){ m_nameDir = std::tuple<QString, EPinDirection>("noNamePin", EPinDirection_Unknown);}
    cPin(QString name, EPinDirection dir) { m_nameDir = std::tuple<QString, EPinDirection>(name, dir); }
    const std::tuple<QString,EPinDirection>& getNameDir() const {return m_nameDir;};
};

class cConnection{
    std::tuple<const cPin&,const cPin&> m_data;

public :
    cConnection();
    cConnection(const cPin& start, const cPin& stop) {m_data = std::tuple<const cPin&, const cPin&>(start, stop);}

    int setData(const cPin& start, const cPin& stop) {m_data = std::tuple<const cPin&, const cPin&>(start, stop);}
    const std::tuple<const cPin&,const  cPin&> & getData() const {return m_data;}
};
```

The compilation fails with message:   cannot convert from 'int' to 'const cPin &'. The indicated line number is at the declaration of the tuple in the cConnection.

I have no idea why. What could be the cause?

Comment: Maybe a lack of implicit conversion from `int` to `const cPin &`? No way.

Comment: There's more than just one error in that program. Please fix everything but the error you want us to focus on.

Comment: @набиячлевэлиь Actually, conversion does not seem to be an issue here at all. OP is assigning to a *const reference* (indirectly), which simply won't work.

Comment: thanks for the reply, dyp. I am afraid I do not know what to focus on.. :(

Comment: @MihaiGALOS Reduce the program until it compiles. Then, add some of the removed parts again until it starts failing to compile. (For example, if you remove the `setData` and `getData` functions, it still won't compile.)

Comment: Well, ok. It seemed bearbones enough to post, but I see.

Apparently, commenting the cConnection::setData, cConnection::getData and the second cConnection constructor compiles. If I uncomment the second constructor, it fails again. It fails even if the second constructor is empty.

Comment: Think of the `std::tuple<const cPin&, const cPin&>` as literally a pair of `const cPin&`. What happens and what do you need to do when you have a `const cPin&` data member in a class?

Comment: I need access to some of its members, through getters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compile error is due to the compiler attempting to initialize `cConnection::m_data` with a default value. Since the tuple is expecting two const references, it can't do this and therefore the error is generated.

You can fix this by removing the default constructor for `cConnection`, and changing the remaining constructor to use an initializer:

```
class cConnection {
    std::tuple<const cPin&, const cPin&> m_data;

public:
    cConnection(const cPin& start, const cPin& stop)
      : m_data(std::tuple<const cPin&, const cPin&>(start, stop)) {
    }
}
```

(You could also fix this by changing the tuple to have pointers rather than references, but that might not make sense in the context of your program.)

If you would like to simplify the code further, consider using `std::make_tuple` (which can infer the type arugments) rather than the `tuple` constructor:

```
class cConnection {
    std::tuple<const cPin&, const cPin&> m_data;

public:
    cConnection(const cPin& start, const cPin& stop)
      : m_data(std::make_tuple(start, stop)) {
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you Andy. So the default constructor was trying to instantiate the m_data! I see. I actually did try with pointers and it compiled, you have answered a hidden question as well! :)

Comment: @MihaiGALOS glad to help :) In general try to use initializers when you can - otherwise all members will be initialized twice (once to their default value, and then again in the body of the constructor).

Comment: @dyp I updated my answer based on your comments. Thanks for the input. :)